# Batch List files in folder and subfolder according to specific format

Tags: batch-file

I am having an question
Is it possible to make an batch file that read the dir and subdirs and output the results in an specific format into an .txt file?

I know how to read the dir including sub dirs etc.
But what i dont know is how i can use an specific format to an .txt file.

Example i have

```
c:\patch
c:\patch\subfolder
c:\patch\subfolder\subfolder
```

In those folders i have some files
What i need is that the output will be something like this

```
2014-05-17  03:16p             7155712 file.exe
2014-05-11  03:41p            19287692 subfolder\file1.res
2014-05-11  03:42p            35508951 subfolder\subsubfolder\file1.res
```

etc.

With kind regards,

Thomas de Vries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Small modifications as reply to the comments.

The following two points have been modified:

- Convert date from DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD.
- Minor adjustments in the output format.

.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "base=%CD%"
set "base=%base:*:=%\"

for /R %%a in (*.*) do (
   for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/-. " %%b in ("%%~Ta") do set "dateTime=%%d-%%c-%%b  %%e%%f"
   set "size=                   %%~Za"
   set name=%%~PNXa
   echo !dateTime! !size:~-19! !name:%base%=!
)
```

Comment: Thank you for youre quick answer. And it almost worked except for 1 thing.

i am getting this 

17-05-2014 12:28          
instead of
2014-05-17 how could i change that?

Comment: Well i solved the issue with the datetime format. Now there is only i thing for me to figure it out and thats this

if we look at these examples

2014-05-17 12:28                     0 file.txt
2014-05-17 03:16               7155712 file2.txt
2014-05-17 12:28              28735405 file3.txt

You will notice the spaces after the time. This is crucial tha the lest 2 things are in the right spot. So how do i manage that?

Comment: I modified the output format in order to match _exactly_ your output example.

Comment: Thank you for the Edit it works like an charm now.
i only have 1 question left. As it stands for now this file must be in the same dir that i whant to read out. Is there an way that i can determine in what path it must search?

For example i place the file inside c:\program and i whant that it can read the contents of c:\Patch what do i need to alter?

Comment: Hi Yesterday i noticed that the above code is also inputting an non-printable character or Control character 016(DLE: Data Link Escape) How can i remove that? If i am using an c++ program for creating an list.txt i dont have any problems.