# Batch after creating an .txt file i have an wierd symbol.

Tags: batch-file

I have asked the following question
[Batch List files in folder and subfolder according to specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744767/batch-list-files-in-folder-and-subfolder-according-to-specific-format/23746571?noredirect=1#comment36514170_23746571)

And this is answered correctly but when i call an program that looks inside the list
I am getting an wierd symbol

With c++ i have an program that will patch files but when i open the program i am getting an

[image: Pathcer error]

See the symbol before the forward slash!.

After I searched on the internet i am stumbled on this
DLE Data Link Escape

Now my question is how do i get rid of the DLE with the batch?
I was thinking maybe its not in ANSI format
So I have tried this

```
for %%a in (%LOCAL_RESCLIENT_DIR%\list.txt %LOCAL_RESCLIENT_DIR%\list.?txt?)  
    do attrib -r -h -s "%%a"
```

But the results are the same.

If someone could explain it to me way i get the DLE then i can proceed.

With kind regards,

Thomas de Vries

Comment: I suggest you correct the script that created the file...

Comment: I would if i know how an DLE (Data Link Escape) is Produced.

Cause i dont see an problem in the code.