# Batch List all Folders and Subfolders in an specific format

Tags: batch-file

I am having an question that is an follow up of my previous question
[Batch List files in folder and subfolder according to specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744767/batch-list-files-in-folder-and-subfolder-according-to-specific-format)

Now that script is working fine is it generates the list.txt that i need. However i need to have some adjustments to it and honestly i dont know where and or how to start with it.

i have multiple folders inside the root folder each of those folders can contain an subfolder and that subfolder also can contain an subsubfolder.

Now what i am looking for is an whay to change the code so that the output is something like this

```
Ver:24
 C:\\RESCLIENT

2014-05-27  09:37            29293018  Pandora_00.res
2014-05-27  15:41      <DIR>           Char
2014-05-11  15:41            19287692  Char\Pandora_00.res
2014-05-11  15:45      <DIR>           World
2014-05-11  15:45      <DIR>           WdMadrigal
2014-05-11  15:50            19287692  WdMadrigal\Pandora_00.res
```

If someone could help me with this i would appriciate it very much.

With kind regards,

Thomas de vries.

EDIT
I forgot to mention 1 thing in my example of the specific output.

We have 2 folders and an couple of files inside the Root dir
Now it must be in this format

```
C:\\RESCLIENT

2014-05-27  08:52p      <DIR>          Char
2014-05-27  08:52p      <DIR>          Client
2014-05-27  09:29p                   0 Flyff.a
2014-05-27  08:52p      <DIR>          Icon
2014-05-27  08:52p      <DIR>          Item
2014-05-27  08:53p      <DIR>          Model
2014-05-27  08:52p            29293018 Pandora_00.res
2014-05-27  08:53p      <DIR>          SFX
2014-05-27  08:53p      <DIR>          Weather
2014-05-27  08:51p      <DIR>          World

 C:\\RESCLIENT\\Char
2014-05-27  08:52p            19287692 Pandora_00.res

 C:\\RESCLIENT\\Client
2014-05-27  08:52p              506652 Pandora_00.res
```

How can i accomplish that.
I know its changed an lot but i forgot the the C++ Program reads it in this format and not the other one.

My apologize for the inconvenience

With kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "base=%CD%\"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S') do (
   for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/-. " %%b in ("%%~Ta") do set "dateTime=%%d-%%c-%%b  %%e%%f"
   set name=%%a
   set attrib=%%~Aa
   if /I "!attrib:~0,1!" neq "d" (
      set "size=                   %%~Za"
      echo !dateTime! !size:~-19! !name:%base%=!
   ) else (
      echo !dateTime!      ^<DIR^>           !name:%base%=!
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the code from the previous answers and with a little formatting, ...

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    :: Select where to start listing files

    if "%~1"=="" (set "startingFolder=%cd%") else (set "startingFolder=%~1")

    :: Determine the length of the starting path to remove
    :: it from output and normalize the path inside the 
    :: starting folder variable

    for /d %%a in ("%startingFolder%\"
    ) do for /f "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=:" %%b in (
        '(echo(%%~fa^&echo(^)^|findstr /o "^"'
    ) do ( set /a "cutPoint=%%b-3" & set "startingFolder=%%~fa" )

    :: Show header

    echo(
    echo(%startingFolder%
    echo(

    if not exist "%startingFolder%" (
        endlocal 
        echo Error, folder not found >&2
        exit /b 1
    )

    :: Retrieve the list of files and folders under starting
    :: folder, correctly sorted, to a temporary file. This avoids
    :: problems with for /f handling large sets of data retrieved
    :: from a command execution

    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"
    dir "%startingFolder%*" /s /b 2>nul | sort > "%tempFile%"

    :: Read the temporary file and, for each of the lines=files/folders
    :: select the adecuated format to output

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%tempFile%") do (
        set "_name=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "_attribs=%%~aa"

        if "!_attribs:~0,1!"=="d" (
            set "_size=      <DIR>         "
        ) else (
            set "_size=                    %%~za"
        )
        echo(%%~ta !_size:~-20! !_name:~%cutPoint%!
        endlocal
    )

    :: Cleanup and exit
    del /q "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
    endlocal

    exit /b
```

**EDITED** Converted recursive `dir` operation into a recursive calling subroutine

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :myCustomDIR %1

    exit /b

:myCustomDIR startingPoint
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    if "%~1"=="" (set "startingFolder=%cd%") else (set "startingFolder=%~1")

    :: normalize the path inside the starting folder variable
    for /d %%a in ("%startingFolder%\") do set "startingFolder=%%~fa"

    echo(
    echo(%startingFolder%
    echo(

    if not exist "%startingFolder%" (
        endlocal 
        echo Error, folder not found >&2
        exit /b 1
    )

    :: List files/folders into current level
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /on /b "%startingFolder%*"'
    ) do for %%b in ("%startingFolder%%%~a") do (
        set "_name=%%b"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "_attribs=%%~ab"

        if "!_attribs:~0,1!"=="d" (
            set "_size=      <DIR>         "
        ) else (
            set "_size=                    %%~zb"
        )
        echo(%%~tb !_size:~-20! %%~nxb
        endlocal
    )

    :: Cleanup this level and call for any lower folder
    endlocal & for /d %%a in ("%startingFolder%*") do call :myCustomDIR "%%a"

    exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you for the code its working for the First Part of my list.txt

Please take an look at my original post that i have edited. Cause i have an second part thats needed.

Comment: @ThomasdeVries, changed. Adapt as needed.

Comment: Thank you for this

I only need to know 1 thing and that is this
the output is know e:\Pandoraflyff\Resclient and for its subfolder e:\Pandoraflyff\Resclient\Char
How do i replace e:\Pandoraflyff\Resclient to this C:\\RESCLIENT and for subfolder C:\\RESCLIENT\Char

Again thank you verry much for the help